# failed when converting date and/or time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am getting value from store procedure in date is `3/25/13 10:06:38 AM` and i want to convert this `03/25/2013 10:18:28` . How can i convert this in sql server . Because when i cast this in date time i am getting error . Below `@PODTimeOnly is varchar(255)` Here i am casting only time and after this i want to cast and store date in another variable.

```
SET @PODTimeOnly = cast(@PODTime as time)
```

ERROR MSG :

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Thanks

Comment: If you could avoid passing this around as a string in the first place, it would be far better. Try to keep everything in suitable variables (`date`/`time`/`datetime`/`datetime2`) throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand the desired output, but if you're forced to hack strings together to generate differently formatted datetime values, this may work.

```
DECLARE @strDate VARCHAR(50) = '3/25/13 10:06:38 AM',
        @dtDate DATETIME,
        @DateOnly VARCHAR(255),
        @TimeOnly VARCHAR(255),
        @output VARCHAR(255)

-- cast to datetime first to verify its a valid date
SET @dtDate = CAST(@strDate AS DATETIME)

-- parse/cast date and time to seperate variables
SET @DateOnly = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),@dtDate,101)
SET @TimeOnly = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),@dtDate,108)

-- duct tape them back together in the desired string format
SET @output = @DateOnly + ' ' + @TimeOnly

-- outputs '03/25/2013 10:06:38'
SELECT @output AS 'NewStringDate'
```